# The incoming tabular data stream remote procedure call protocol stream is incorrect. Too many parameters were provided in this RPC request

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-2008

I am facing an error which is:

> The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. Too many parameters were provided in this RPC request. The maximum is 2100.

I have done some code where it is coming. The code is given below.

```
 var statements = session.Query<TBAStatementBankAccount>().Where(x => x.TBABankAccount == bankAccount).ToList().Select(x => x.TBAStatement).ToList();

            var lstStatement = session.Query<TBAStatement>().Where(x => statements.Contains(x) && x.FDate < CutOffDate).ToList();
            var lstDate = lstStatement.OrderByDescending(x => x.FDate).ToList();
```

When I debug the code var statement retrieve around 8000 record. My problem is that how can I use In(Contains) method in lambda expression. I am stuck in this problem.

Answer (score 3):

i have implement some code for above issue and it is working fine at my end.The code is given below.

```
var statements = session.Query<TBAStatementBankAccount>().Where(x => x.TBABankAccount == bankAccount).ToList().Select(x => x.TBAStatement).ToList();
 var sublists = statements
                .Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, Value = x })
                .GroupBy(x => x.Index / 2000)
                .Select(x => x.Select(v => v.Value).ToList())
                .ToArray();

            List<TBAStatement> lstNewstatement = new List<TBAStatement>();
            foreach (var statemnt in sublists)
            {            
                var state = session.Query<TBAStatement>().Where(x => statemnt.Contains(x) && x.FDate < CutOffDate).ToList();
                lstNewstatement.AddRange(state);
            }
```